# Adding style to custom wordpress menu

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm using the bones starter theme, and have already created one menu that looks like it's supposed to. It's called like this:

```
<?php bones_main_nav(); ?>
```

and in the css it's styled simply by using the .menu class.

Now I've created an alternate menu that will be used on some pages. I want it to have the exact same style applied to as the first one, only include different pages. I've called it like this:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'my custom menu' )); ?>
```

That shows the right pages but I can't seem to figure out how to apply the same styles to it that are already applied to the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I figured it out for myself, just had to pass the attributes like this:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'custom menu', 'menu_class' => 'menu', 'container_class' =>  'menu clearfix', 'theme_location' => 'main_nav')) ?>
```